# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory | Elastic Search

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, machine-learning, runtime-error

I'm fairly new to Machine Learning. I've successfully solved errors to do with parameters and model setup.

I'm using this [Notebook](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial16_Document_Classifier_at_Index_Time.ipynb), where section **Apply DocumentClassifier** is altered as below.

**Jupyter Labs**, kernel: `conda_mxnet_latest_p37`.

---

Error seems to be more about my laptop's hardware, rather than my code being broken.

Update: I changed `batch_size=4`, it ran for ages only to crash.

**What should be my standard approach to solving this error?**

---

**My Code:**

```py
with open('filt_gri.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    tags = [current_place.rstrip() for current_place in filehandle.readlines()]

doc_classifier = TransformersDocumentClassifier(model_name_or_path="cross-encoder/nli-distilroberta-base",
                                                task="zero-shot-classification",
                                                labels=tags,
                                                batch_size=4)

# convert to Document using a fieldmap for custom content fields the classification should run on
docs_to_classify = [Document.from_dict(d) for d in docs_sliding_window]

# classify using gpu, batch_size makes sure we do not run out of memory
classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)

# let's see how it looks: there should be a classification result in the meta entry containing labels and scores.
print(classified_docs[0].to_dict())

all_docs = convert_files_to_dicts(dir_path=doc_dir)

preprocessor_sliding_window = PreProcessor(split_overlap=3,
                                           split_length=10,
                                           split_respect_sentence_boundary=False,
                                           split_by='passage')
```

**Error:**

```
INFO - haystack.modeling.utils -  Using devices: CUDA
INFO - haystack.modeling.utils -  Using devices: CUDA
INFO - haystack.modeling.utils -  Number of GPUs: 1
INFO - haystack.modeling.utils -  Number of GPUs: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-27dfca549a7d> in <module>
     14 
     15 # classify using gpu, batch_size makes sure we do not run out of memory
---> 16 classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)
     17 
     18 # let's see how it looks: there should be a classification result in the meta entry containing labels and scores.

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haystack/nodes/document_classifier/transformers.py in predict(self, documents)
    137         batches = self.get_batches(texts, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    138         if self.task == 'zero-shot-classification':
--> 139             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, candidate_labels=self.labels, truncation=True) for batch in batches]
    140         elif self.task == 'text-classification':
    141             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, return_all_scores=self.return_all_scores, truncation=True) for batch in batches]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haystack/nodes/document_classifier/transformers.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    137         batches = self.get_batches(texts, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    138         if self.task == 'zero-shot-classification':
--> 139             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, candidate_labels=self.labels, truncation=True) for batch in batches]
    140         elif self.task == 'text-classification':
    141             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, return_all_scores=self.return_all_scores, truncation=True) for batch in batches]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/zero_shot_classification.py in __call__(self, sequences, candidate_labels, hypothesis_template, multi_label, **kwargs)
    151             sequences = [sequences]
    152 
--> 153         outputs = super().__call__(sequences, candidate_labels, hypothesis_template)
    154         num_sequences = len(sequences)
    155         candidate_labels = self._args_parser._parse_labels(candidate_labels)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    759     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    760         inputs = self._parse_and_tokenize(*args, **kwargs)
--> 761         return self._forward(inputs)
    762 
    763     def _forward(self, inputs, return_tensors=False):

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py in _forward(self, inputs, return_tensors)
    780                 with torch.no_grad():
    781                     inputs = self.ensure_tensor_on_device(**inputs)
--> 782                     predictions = self.model(**inputs)[0].cpu()
    783 
    784         if return_tensors:

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1162             output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1163             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
-> 1164             return_dict=return_dict,
   1165         )
   1166         sequence_output = outputs[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    823             output_attentions=output_attentions,
    824             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
--> 825             return_dict=return_dict,
    826         )
    827         sequence_output = encoder_outputs[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    513                     encoder_attention_mask,
    514                     past_key_value,
--> 515                     output_attentions,
    516                 )
    517 

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    398             head_mask,
    399             output_attentions=output_attentions,
--> 400             past_key_value=self_attn_past_key_value,
    401         )
    402         attention_output = self_attention_outputs[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    328             encoder_attention_mask,
    329             past_key_value,
--> 330             output_attentions,
    331         )
    332         attention_output = self.output(self_outputs[0], hidden_states)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    241                 attention_scores = attention_scores + relative_position_scores_query + relative_position_scores_key
    242 
--> 243         attention_scores = attention_scores / math.sqrt(self.attention_head_size)
    244         if attention_mask is not None:
    245             # Apply the attention mask is (precomputed for all layers in RobertaModel forward() function)

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 3.60 GiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 7.33 GiB already allocated; 1.37 GiB free; 12.29 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-27dfca549a7d> in <module>
     14 
     15 # classify using gpu, batch_size makes sure we do not run out of memory
---> 16 classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)
     17 
     18 # let's see how it looks: there should be a classification result in the meta entry containing labels and scores.

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haystack/nodes/document_classifier/transformers.py in predict(self, documents)
    137         batches = self.get_batches(texts, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    138         if self.task == 'zero-shot-classification':
--> 139             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, candidate_labels=self.labels, truncation=True) for batch in batches]
    140         elif self.task == 'text-classification':
    141             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, return_all_scores=self.return_all_scores, truncation=True) for batch in batches]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haystack/nodes/document_classifier/transformers.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    137         batches = self.get_batches(texts, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    138         if self.task == 'zero-shot-classification':
--> 139             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, candidate_labels=self.labels, truncation=True) for batch in batches]
    140         elif self.task == 'text-classification':
    141             batched_predictions = [self.model(batch, return_all_scores=self.return_all_scores, truncation=True) for batch in batches]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/zero_shot_classification.py in __call__(self, sequences, candidate_labels, hypothesis_template, multi_label, **kwargs)
    151             sequences = [sequences]
    152 
--> 153         outputs = super().__call__(sequences, candidate_labels, hypothesis_template)
    154         num_sequences = len(sequences)
    155         candidate_labels = self._args_parser._parse_labels(candidate_labels)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    759     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    760         inputs = self._parse_and_tokenize(*args, **kwargs)
--> 761         return self._forward(inputs)
    762 
    763     def _forward(self, inputs, return_tensors=False):

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py in _forward(self, inputs, return_tensors)
    780                 with torch.no_grad():
    781                     inputs = self.ensure_tensor_on_device(**inputs)
--> 782                     predictions = self.model(**inputs)[0].cpu()
    783 
    784         if return_tensors:

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1162             output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1163             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
-> 1164             return_dict=return_dict,
   1165         )
   1166         sequence_output = outputs[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    823             output_attentions=output_attentions,
    824             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
--> 825             return_dict=return_dict,
    826         )
    827         sequence_output = encoder_outputs[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    513                     encoder_attention_mask,
    514                     past_key_value,
--> 515                     output_attentions,
    516                 )
    517 

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    398             head_mask,
    399             output_attentions=output_attentions,
--> 400             past_key_value=self_attn_past_key_value,
    401         )
    402         attention_output = self_attention_outputs[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    328             encoder_attention_mask,
    329             past_key_value,
--> 330             output_attentions,
    331         )
    332         attention_output = self.output(self_outputs[0], hidden_states)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    241                 attention_scores = attention_scores + relative_position_scores_query + relative_position_scores_key
    242 
--> 243         attention_scores = attention_scores / math.sqrt(self.attention_head_size)
    244         if attention_mask is not None:
    245             # Apply the attention mask is (precomputed for all layers in RobertaModel forward() function)

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 3.60 GiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 7.33 GiB already allocated; 1.37 GiB free; 12.29 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

**Original Code:**

```py
doc_classifier = TransformersDocumentClassifier(model_name_or_path="cross-encoder/nli-distilroberta-base",
    task="zero-shot-classification",
    labels=["music", "natural language processing", "history"],
    batch_size=16
)

# ----------

# convert to Document using a fieldmap for custom content fields the classification should run on
docs_to_classify = [Document.from_dict(d) for d in docs_sliding_window]

# ----------

# classify using gpu, batch_size makes sure we do not run out of memory
classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)

# ----------

# let's see how it looks: there should be a classification result in the meta entry containing labels and scores.
print(classified_docs[0].to_dict())
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should add to post/ clarify.

Comment: `batch_size=4` is taking forever to load, but not crashing. A good sign.

Comment: This eventually crashed ;( Updating post

Comment: Running `batch_size=2`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reducing** the `batch_size` helped me:

```
batch_size=2
```

Comment: Will approve answer in 2 days